# Flat modules and exactness

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Assume N is flat. i want to conclude that $Tor_n(M,N)=0 \forall n>0$ and for any module $M$. To prove this I took a projective resolution $P_{.}$ of M and tensored with N. By assumption N is flat so how can i conclude that $P_{.} \otimes N$ is also exact? Is it true that if $A \to B \to C$ is exact and N is flat implies $A \otimes N \to B \otimes N \to C\otimes N$ is also exact. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $0\to K\to P\to M\to 0$, with $P$ projective. Then the long exact sequence tells you
$$
\operatorname{Tor}_{n}(P,N)\to
\operatorname{Tor}_{n}(M,N)\to
\operatorname{Tor}_{n-1}(K,N)
$$
is exact for all $n>1$. Since $P$ is projective, $\operatorname{Tor}_{n}(P,N)=0$ for all $n\ge1$. Moreover $\operatorname{Tor}_{n-1}(K,N)=0$ by inductive hypothesis. The base case comes from exactness of
$$
\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(P,N)\to
\operatorname{Tor}_{1}(M,N)\to
K\otimes N\to P\otimes N
$$
and exactness of $0\to K\otimes N\to P\otimes N$.

Comment: I didnt follow the base case. Can you elaborate little more? So is it true that if N is flat and $A \to B\to C $ is exact then the tensored sequence is also exact?

Comment: @AnupamAh Since $\operatorname{Tor}_1(P,N)=0$ (because $P$ is projective) and $K\otimes N\to P\otimes N$ is a monomorphism, its kernel (which is $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M,N)$) is zero. Flatness means that the tensor product preserves monomorphisms. But, yes, if a functor $F$ is exact, then it preserves exactness of exact sequences of any length.

Comment: So if it preserves exact sequences of any length can we tell directly that $Tor_n(M,N)=0$ since $Tor_n$ taking homology at nth level of $P_. \otimes N$ where $P_.$ is a proj resoln for M.

Comment: @AnupamAh That's another way for proving the result.